# socket operation unreachable to host

Tags: oracle

I have a problem when accessing an oracle server. This problem appears when I try to remotely access the server and hwen opening a web page from client to server.

> socket operation unreachable to host

The IP address is in the same network `database server: 10.0.0.60` and `client : 10.0.7.x` and the subnet mask of client and server are both `255.0.0.0' The cable is not the problem and when i pinging from client to server the result is reply so not problem in the network card.

note: the network was working very good after that.

Answer (score 0):

First steps with any network issue are

1. Can you PING the remote host from the local host
2. If not, the remote host is down or a firewall is blocking the two
3. If you can, can you TELNET to the relevent port on the remote host from the local
4. If not, maybe nothing is listening on that port or the firewall is blocking it
5. If you can TELNET but the remote host isn't responding to the expected connection, it may be a protocol issue (eg trying to send HTTP to a database listener)